# How to align auto generated content DataTemplate next to each other?

Tags: c#, xaml

i want those buttons next to each other and not under each other

this is a mvvm, so the buttons are generated by a class

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}" Grid.Column="1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button Margin="8" Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the default [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) from your `ItemsControl` into a horizontal oriented one, here's an example :

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
              <Button Margin="8" Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

By defining an horizontal `StackPanel` as your `ItemsControl` panel, each item will be aligned next to each other (Note that the default one is a vertical `StackPanel`).

Comment: You're welcome! If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help future readers to find what they need (and trust it) and will help to keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers ;)